# ExtJS 3 multiple stateful grids (but with different stateIds)

Tags: extjs, grid, state, extjs3

I have my grid, which overwrites Ext.grid.GridPanel

I use this grid in 2 places on my site. I generate 2 **different** stateIds for them:

constructor:

```
TasksGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    id: genId,
    cls: 'tasks-grid',
    border: false,
    loadMask: {msg: 'Loading...'},
    sm: sm,
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'tasks-grid'+(config.booClientTab ? '-clients-tab' : ''), // depending on config.booClientTab I setup one or other stateId
...
```

this code I call in 2 places on site to create 2 grids:

```
this.TasksGrid = new TasksGrid(this, {
    region: 'west',
    split: true,
    width: tasksGridWidth ? tasksGridWidth : defaultWidth,
    booShowToolbar: true,
    booClientTab: !empty(config.clientId) // if true, 1 stateId will be setup, false - other
});
```

But, when I test, state is applied only to first of 2 generated grids!! I checked cookies: seems, that all works fine: 2 cookies with 2 different names are created. But... State applies only to first call of "this.TasksGrid = new TasksGrid"!!!

ExtJS version: 3.0

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. State can be applied to the component only during initialization not after initialization. Therefore it works for the first time but not after. Luckily you are using EextJs 3 and following piece of code worked for me in ExtJS 3 but not in 4. Basically when you apply new/other state to the grid just call

```
MyGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel,
{
    /* @private */
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        MyGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },
    initComponent: function()
    {
        var cfg =
        {
            border: true,
            bodyBorder: false,
            stateful: true,
            stateId: 'grid',
            tbar:
                [{
                    text: 'View name'
                },{
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    width: 80,
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    mode: 'local',
                    forceSelection: true,
                    hiddenName: 'stateId',
                    selectOnFocus:true,
                    displayField:'name',
                    ref: '../stateCombo',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    listeners:
                    {
                        scope: this,
                        change: function(combo, newValue, oldValue)
                        {
                            newValue = parseInt(newValue, 10); var grd = this;
                            grd.el.mask('Applying the view please wait');
                            var data = combo.store.data.items;
                            Ext.each(data, function(d)
                            {
                                d.data.id = parseInt(d.data.id, 10);
                                if(d.data.id === newValue)
                                {
                                    Ext.util.Cookies.set('reportStateName', d.data.machineName);
                                    grd.applyState(MyStateProvider.decodeState(d.data.value));
                                    var conf = grd.getColumnModel().config;
                                    grd.getColumnModel().setConfig(conf);
                                    grd.doLayout();
                                    grd.getView().updateAllColumnWidths();
                                    grd.getView().refresh(true);
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                            grd.el.unmask();
                            grd = null;
                        }
                    },
                    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore
                        ({
                            fields:
                                [{
                                    name: 'id',
                                    type: 'int'
                                }],
                            proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy
                                ({
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    url: BASEURL + 'getsavedstate'
                                }),
                            idProperty: 'id'
                        })
                }]
        };
        //we use applyIf for configuration attributes that should be left configurable
        Ext.applyIf(this, cfg);
        //ensure that any extra configurations that are set in initComponent method are applied to initialConfig:
        Ext.applyIf(this.initialConfig, cfg);
        /*
         * Properties specified here are safe/protected from being overridden
         * by an instance, so any 'private' default properties might be specified here.
         */
        //some attributes we may want to keep unaltered, so we use Ext.apply non-alterable configurables
        cfg =
        {
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
            stripeRows: true,
            loadMask: true
        };
        Ext.apply(this, cfg);
        //need this to work sometimes:
        Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, cfg);
        MyGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        this.on
            ({
                afterrender: function(grid)
                {
                    var grd = this;
                    this.stateCombo.getStore().load
                        ({
                            callback: function(data, options, success)
                            {
                                grd.saveAsStateBtn.enable();
                                var applied = false;
                                var setStateValue = Ext.util.Cookies.get('reportStateName');
                                Ext.each(data, function(d)
                                {
                                    //meaning no cookie was set so first time.
                                    if(setStateValue === null)
                                    {
                                        if(d.data.machineName === 'default')
                                        {
                                            if(d.data.value !== '')
                                            {
                                                grd.applyState(MyStateProvider.decodeState(d.data.value));
                                                applied = true;
                                                grd.stateCombo.setValue(d.data.id);
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            applied = true;
                                            grd.stateCombo.setValue(d.data.id);//Here value should be fetched from cookie
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else//Cookie was set
                                    {
                                        if(d.data.machineName === setStateValue)
                                        {
                                            if(d.data.value !== '')
                                            {
                                                var s = MyStateProvider.decodeState(d.data.value);
                                                grd.applyState(s);
                                                applied = true;
                                                grd.stateCombo.setValue(d.data.id);//Here value should be fetched from cookie
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                //grd.doLayout();
                                if(data.length !== 0)
                                {
                                    grd.stateCombo.enable();
                                    grd.saveStateBtn.enable();
                                }
                                var conf = grd.getColumnModel().config;
                                grd.getColumnModel().setConfig(conf);
                                grd.doLayout();
                                grd.getView().updateAllColumnWidths();
                                grd.getView().refresh(true);
                                grd.doLayout();
                                grd.el.unmask();
                            }
                        });
                    this.el.mask('Applying the saved view please wait');
                },
                scope: this
            });
    },
    onRender: function (container, position)
    {
        MyGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
        var el = this.el;
        var grd = this;
        this.saveStateWindow = new MySaveStateWindow
            ({
                grid: grd,
                renderTo: el
            });
    },
    // template method
    /* @private */
    initEvents: function()
    {
        MyGrid.superclass.initEvents.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    afterRender: function()
    {
        MyGrid.superclass.afterRender.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    // template method
    /* @private */
    beforeDestroy: function()
    {
        //Call parent
        MyGrid.superclass.beforeDestroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    onDestroy: function()
    {
        this.saveStateWindow.destroy();
        MyGrid.superclass.onDestroy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but seems, it doesn't help... Or I do not use your code correctly.

I copied/pasted your code after "this.TasksGrid = new TasksGrid" block, replacing your var grid with my var this.TasksGrid

Comment: You have to apply the code after you apply the state like this grid.applyState(state); During initialization of the grid itself above code is not required.

Comment: I have the same issue too, so can you (nicholasnet) show us the full working example?

Comment: Thanks @nicholasnet for example. But what is not clear for me - you set grid as stateful and haven't used that state id later. 

You only loaded and set info from information you saved in combobox item (and previously loaded from server). As I understood - `fcunited` needs to load state of the columns when grid will be rendered second time. So how we can get current state and load it when we need?